# shim class is not generating all public methods

Tags: c#, testing

I have defined a ShimGeneration for a class in my code under test. The shim class was generated, but 1 public method of the original class is missing in the shim class. The original method signature is:

```
public MemoryStream GetServerData(string requestType, string url, MemoryStream requestData)
```

I suspect that the problem is the MemoryStream type. How do I tell my fakes assembly to know about MemoryStream?

My fakes assembly looks like (ServerComm is the class I want to generate a shim class for):

```
<Fakes xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/fakes/2011/" Diagnostic="true">
  <Assembly Name="MyProject"/>
  <StubGeneration>
    <Clear/>
  </StubGeneration>
  <ShimGeneration>
    <Clear/>
    <Add Full Name="ServerComm"/>
  </ShimGeneration>
</Fakes>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have to do some investigations but Shims will definitely work with base class (tested on .net 4.5):

```
public Stream GetServerData(string requestType, string url, Stream requestData)
```

**EDIT 1**

I have changed Target framework to version 4.6 (only test project) and it works also with `MemoryStream`.

Comment: It's weird. I added a simple method to the original class:

Comment: Does it generate Shim for the simple method you have added?

Comment: It's weird. I added a simple method to the original class:
        public void DoNothing(string str)
        {
        }
rebuilt the whole solution, but the shim class file was not updated with the new method. The weird thing is that I got this new method suggestion when I typed MyProject.Fakes.ShimServerComm.AllInstances.
How do I get the shim class file regenerated?

Comment: I in your configuration - `<Add Full Name="ServerComm"/>` it should be  `<Add FullName="ServerComm"/>`

Comment: It is <Add FullName="ServerComm"/>
For some reason, the paste injected the space

Comment: What do you mean by shim class file?  Do you mean generated code by VS, that is located `\TestprojectName\obj\Debug\Fakes...`? I believe that rebuild test project should do the job.

Comment: Yes, I mean that file. Rebuilding the test project is not regenerating it. Only when I delete my fakes assembly and start the whole procedure anew, the file is generated.